# Does running SKAction.repeatForever for an animation cause considerable CPU usage?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3, skaction

While testing my spritekit game, I noticed that using the `SkAction.repeatForever(SkAction.animate())` causes considerable CPU usage. I have a basic 3 texture animation that creates a rising smoke effect. I would think this would be pretty simple.

I run it as follows:
`self.extractorSprite.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: self.extractorAnimation, timePerFrame: 0.4)))`

The problem is that whenever this animation is run, it causes a constant 40% CPU usage which I would think is abnormal. If I comment out this line then CPU usage drops down to 2-7%.

Is there something I am missing about the SKAction? Why is it using so much CPU?

Thanks

*** Update ***
Here is the code for the extractor, the animation is called inside init()

```
class extractor: SKNode {
var extractorSprite:SKSpriteNode!
var extractorAtlas:SKTextureAtlas!
var extractorAnimation:Array<SKTexture> = []

var combatStats:unitCombatStats!
var resourceProduction:Int = 2
var resourceCost:Int = 4
var animation:SKAction!

init(extractorAtlas: SKTextureAtlas){
    super.init()
    self.createExtractor(Atlas: extractorAtlas)
    self.startAnimation()
    self.combatStats = unitCombatStats()
    self.combatStats.setForExtractor()
}

private func createExtractor(Atlas: SKTextureAtlas){
    self.extractorAtlas = Atlas
    for name in Atlas.textureNames {
        self.extractorAnimation.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))
    }

    self.extractorSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: Atlas.textureNames[0])
    self.extractorSprite.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    self.extractorSprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    self.addChild(self.extractorSprite)
}

func startAnimation(){
    self.extractorSprite.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: self.extractorAnimation, timePerFrame: 0.4, resize: false, restore: true)), withKey: "ext-Animation")
}

func modifyColor(color: SKColor, blendfactor: CGFloat, blendMode: SKBlendMode){
    self.extractorSprite.blendMode = blendMode
    self.extractorSprite.colorBlendFactor = blendfactor
    self.extractorSprite.color = color
}
func modifySpawnPosition(position: CGPoint){
    self.extractorSprite.position = position
}
func modifyExtractorSize(newSize: CGSize){
    self.extractorSprite.size = newSize
}

func getNodeCopy(andNameIt: String) -> extractor {
    let copiedNode = extractor(extractorAtlas: self.extractorAtlas)
    copiedNode.name = andNameIt
    copiedNode.extractorSprite.size = self.extractorSprite.size
    copiedNode.isHidden = false
    return copiedNode
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.extractorSprite = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "extractorSprite") as? SKSpriteNode
    self.extractorAnimation = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "extractorAnimation") as? Array<SKTexture>)!
    self.extractorAtlas = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "extractorAtlas") as? SKTextureAtlas
}

override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(self.extractorSprite, forKey: "extractorSprite")
    aCoder.encode(self.extractorAnimation, forKey: "extractorAnimation")
    aCoder.encode(self.extractorAtlas, forKey: "extractorAtlas")
}
```

}

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: need to see `extractorAnimation` and `extractorSprite` content to know what's flogging the CPU. I suspect it's an `SKEffectNode` you're using, but just guessing.

Comment: Does the posted code help?

Comment: Do you actually need to do a 'repeatForever' on an 'animate(with: textures)'. Isn't the animate(with:) enough?

Comment: Well an animate(with:) will only do it once which isn't very convincing as a "smoke" effect. A factory constantly belches smoke. Is spritekit really so CPU inefficient that a repeat forever causes such high CPU load?

Comment: That seems about normal CPU usage for any SpriteKit project regardless of what you do. The onyl reason you see it drop down when you remove that line is because SpriteKit only renders something when there is a change. Games are always CPU/GPU intensive as they are rendering at 60fps or more, though the CPU should not rise much after that. Also, if you're using the simulator it will be even worse.

Comment: That seems to be in line with what I am seeing. Adding the animation makes the CPU rise to as much as 70-80% when other stuff is going on as well, but adding multiple instances of this object doesn't increase it very much after. Guess it's just something to live with. Thank you!